# Testing method which access static final field locally inside method gives error

Tags: java, android, testing

I am new to testing and i have this problem while testing the below code gives null pointer exception.

This is my class of CommonFunctions which contains method for email validation

Source file ----->

```
import android.util.Patterns;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CommonFunctions {

   private Context context;

   public CommonFunctions(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
    }


   //to check whether email is valid or not

    public boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
      Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
      return matcher.matches();
   }

 }
```

The "Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS" is from android.util.Patterns EMAIL_ADDRESS is static final field

---

My Testing code using Junit and Mockito

```
   import android.content.Context;

   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.mockito.Mock;
   import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

   import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
   import static org.junit.Assert.*;


    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class CommonFunctionsTest {

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;


    @Test
    public void isEmailValid() throws Exception {

       CommonFunctions commonFunctions = new CommonFunctions(mMockContext);
        assertThat(commonFunctions.isEmailValid("name@gmail.com"), is(true));

    }

}
```

Error :  java.lang.NullPointerException  at  this line:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
```

in the isEmailValid method  of CommonFunction class

the 'pattern' is still null

that means while testing it I can not access the "Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS" from the android.util.Patterns, EMAIL_ADDRESS is static final field

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The "Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS" is from **android.util**.Patterns

If you're creating this as a standard unit test (in `/test`), then JUnit does not use the Android framework. Any Android-specific methods are stubbed and will fail to run.

You'd either need to define `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` yourself from scratch or run this test as an Instrumentation test in `/androidTest`. Alternatively, take a look at using [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) as it provides an implementation of the Android SDK for use in local JUnit tests.

Answer (score 8):

Just solved it by switching from  `Patterns.EMAIL_ADRESS.matcher()` to `PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADRESS.matcher()`. This should work.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. What could be the reason?